# Stored procedure in SQL Server truncating VARCHAR field

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ssms

I recently encountered a problem with inserting data which is of greater length than the specified column length in SQL Server. I was inserting the data using stored procedure where I specified a parameter type as `varchar(100)`.

The table where I had to insert this data had a column with data type as `VARCHAR(100)`. But unfortunately, data passed to the stored procedure had more than 100 characters.

The SQL Server automatically truncated the string to fit 100 characters and saved the data without throwing any error.

The problem is that, we got to know about the issue after a long time (may be after 1 year) by then, a lot of users had entered a lot of comments which were truncated and a only small portion of their comments were saved. I have seen that there are many ways tackle this, But I couldn't find any possible way to retrieve the lost data (truncated data).

Is there any way in SQL Server to retrieve the truncated part of these comments? Does SQL Server logs this in some kind of log files/tables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the simple answer is "nope, gone for good"

Comment: You must specify the maximum text length in the text box, to avoid this situation.

Comment: SQL Server is very good at storing *the data that you've told it to store*. Other data that you've not told it about? No

Comment: No, that data is gone. This is what happens when you don't test your application.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you, But the part that I was surprised is that the stored procedure automatically truncating the characters when a large string is passed, instead of throwing an error.